# form1.cs cannot be accessed via unit test 1.cs c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

[image]

Hi,

I cannot access Form1 from my unit test file. Here is a screenshot. Could you please advise anyway to overcome this problem. It is changeable to Form, then I cannot access Form1.

Thanks.

Buddhi

Here is further images that s belong to the error[image]

Comment: Could it be that `Form1` is not public? You can try adding the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Assignment4Test")]` assembly attribute to your AssemblyInfo.cs in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify if you have added the reference if Form1 is defined in another project. Also, you should be adding a using statement in your test class.

You can hover the mouse over the error and see what it says.

Comment: Please see the above image whether I did it correct way or not. Thanks

Comment: It appears you may have missed adding using statement. Keep the cursor on Form1 and hit Ctrl+. to see the options.

Comment: The options shown in error04 image are the options when I click Ctrl+. Also where should I add using statement. I did at the beginning of the UnitTest.cs

Comment: Confirm whether Form1 is marked as internal class.

You should be adding the using statement in Assignment4Test.cs file at the top as using Assignment4;

Comment: I think I did it. I have change the form name. I think it is the reason I cannot access it. Thank you for your help